# When using NSPersistentCloudKitContainer: what to do if the user logs out of iCloud?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer, nspersistentcontainer

From several Apple WWDC talks on CloudKit, when using CloudKit to sync private user data across devices, when the user logs out of iCloud, the App is supposed to empty the on-device cache / local replica (I use Core Data for on-device permanence). Then when this user (or any user really) logs back into his respective iCloud account on that same device, the device is then supposed to sync back down the data from the corresponding iCloud account. Makes sense!

I was wondering how I can achieve this when I use NSPersistentCloudKitContainer (instead of writing all that CloudKit code myself). I looked at the sample code related to Apple WWDC 2019 session 202 ("Using Core Data with CloudKit"), and this code does not what I want (the sample just does not focus on the iCloud account part, that is why they do not bother to empty the cache, I think): Indeed the NSPersistentCloudKitContainer stops synching if I log out the user, but it picks up again synching when I log back in. That is actually more like the desired (and indeed also actual, which is good) behaviour by the sample App when my web connection goes offline for a while.

But if the user logs out of iCloud (I use CloudKit framework to be informed about user account logout and login status), what I would need to do is somehow:

1. "disconnect" the sqlite store from the NSPersistentCloudKitContainer, then
2. empty (or even delete) the database, and then,
3. when the old (or another) user logs in, initialise a new NSPersistentCloudKitContainer (that will recreate an empty database as if the App would be used for the first time ever),                           so communication with the respective Cloud database can proceed.

I can not just empty the database WHILE being "connected" to the NSPersistentCloudKitContainer, as it records all the deletes and as soon as the (same) user logs in again, these deletes are synched to the Cloud, which I of course do NOT want.

Is this how one does it, aka essentially follow these three steps?

And if yes, how do I do step 2? Since I must use some kind of NSPersistentContainer to talk to the database, Apple warns not to directly do file system operations but only via Core Data. So do I need to init a "standard" NSPersistentContainer (without a communication pipe to the Cloud), and then destroy the database (e.g. using e.g. the coordinator instance method destroyPersistentStore())?

Or is there another approach for achieving the same thing?

Thank you very much for any help!!

Comment: I am having the similar problem. But the difference is that I don't want to delete the on-device database. When the user logs out iCloud, the app just stop syncing. But when he/she logs back it, the syncing starts again without uploading repetitive data. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you for sharing. No, I did not. I decided now to use CloudKit and Core Data directly. This NSPersistentCloudKitContainer is too much of a black box for me to feel comfortable with it.